# Telegram Bot and Google Script - doPost(e) not triggering

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I can enter text into the bot and it confirms (double check) but never triggers doPost.  I have the web app created and confirmed it's working through the doGet function.  I run getMe and confirms the bot is functioning.  I run SetWebHook and it confirm its set.  I type to the bot and get nothing.  Nothing in the doPost is triggering.  Any suggestions?

```
var token = "xxxxxxxxxx:AAF-abcderKOWIomM1sq3uttOME7bI";    
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbypBHbRswF9NZA_viYsl647JYQhB0fG0w8GL13Cw03kJo8xidJWVEZziP4KVTMjEtpe/exec"; 
var ssId= "1gKGU3ViXnWHm3OBeBtN1mzn-yNymuEmXfV1tT5bNdNw";      
var adminID = "@XXXXXX";   

var sheetname = "Log";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetname);
ss.appendRow(["Got here"]);


function doPost(e) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),"Bot sent email",JSON.stringify(e,null,4));
  var sheetname = "Log";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetname);
  ss.appendRow(["doPost"]);

  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;

}

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id,answer) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(answer);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
}
```

Run getMe - Works
Run setWebHook - Confirmed
Test webappURL- Confirmed

Type into bot - nothing

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Comment: I tested this just adding my own token and URL and the bot webhook sends the message successfully and `doPost()` worked. My guess is that you could have set up the wrong WebApp URL.